# Main title at the top of a plot is cut off

Tags: r, plot, x11

When I plot two graphs after creating a new `x11()` device and want to set a overall title it is not displayed well. The top part of the title string is behind the window top bar. Is there a way to fix this? I couldn't find anything in `?x11` or in the x11 client preferences that helped.

This script:

```
x11()
x <- rnorm(1000, 0, 1)
hist(x)
title('Title', outer = TRUE)
```

Looks like that:

[image]

Comment: Without knowing what plotting routines you are using there is no basis for attempting to reproduce the behavior you are witnessing.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

R does not by default allocate any space to the outer margins; see `par("oma")`.  Try

```
par(oma=c(0,0,2,0))
```

(See `?par` and search for "outer" for more information.)