# R: Titles cut in half with par()

Tags: r, plot, r-corrplot

I have this figure:

```
require(corrplot)
par(oma=c(0,0,2,0), mfrow = c(1, 3))
for (country in c("Italy","Germany","Afghanistan")) {
  corrplot.mixed(cor(data.frame(v1=rnorm(40),
                                v2=rnorm(40),
                                v3=rnorm(40),
                                v4=rnorm(40),
                                v5=rnorm(40),
                                v6=rnorm(40),
                                v7=rnorm(40),
                                v8=rnorm(40)), use="pairwise.complete.obs"),
                 main=country)
}
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
```

which produces titles cut in half:

[image]

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631358/1707938) I set `oma=c(0,0,2,0)` but it does't affect the results. I am not sure which margin I should modify. I looked at `?par` and modified "oma", "omd", "omi", "mai", "mar" with no result.

Comment: It's probably not a base-graphics function.

Comment: @BondedDust Doesn't sound good. Should I then assign the titles out of `corrplot()`?

Comment: Sorry. It is base graphics, but it's setting its own mar parameters. Look at the code with `corrplot::corrplot`. Why not try printing to a graphics file device and  viewing it with an external viewer? Could also try passing the mar arguments inside the `corrplot` call.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found that passing mar arguments to `corrplot` was effective:

```
    png(height=300,width=600);par(oma=c(0,0,2,0), mfrow = c(1, 3))
for (country in c("Italy","Germany","Afghanistan")) {
  corrplot.mixed(cor(data.frame(v1=rnorm(40),
                                v2=rnorm(40),
                                v3=rnorm(40),
                                v4=rnorm(40),
                                v5=rnorm(40),
                                v6=rnorm(40),
                                v7=rnorm(40),
                                v8=rnorm(40)), use="pairwise.complete.obs"),
                 main=country, mar=c(0,0,2,0))
};dev.off()
```

[image]