# How to change the margins of a correlation matrix plot?

Tags: r, plot, margin, correlation, r-corrplot

I couldn't find any option to expand the margins for plot generated by `corrplot.mixed` in the [`corrplot`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html) package. Any suggestion would be appreciated!

```
library(corrplot) 
cor_matrix <- structure(c(1, 0.31596392056465, -0.120092224085334, -0.345097115278159, 
                          0.31596392056465, 1, 0.158912865564527, -0.606426850726639, -0.120092224085334, 
                          0.158912865564527, 1, -0.134795548155303, -0.345097115278159, 
                          -0.606426850726639, -0.134795548155303, 1), .Dim = c(4L, 4L), 
                        .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("var_1", "var_2", "var_3", "var_4")))

corrplot.mixed(cor_matrix, order = "AOE", upper = "ellipse", lower = "number", 
               tl.cex = 2, cl.cex = 2, number.cex = 2)
```

Comment: I suggest looking at the package function itself `fix(corrplot.mixed)` and editing the margins there.

Comment: What do you mean expand the margins? Do you mean just to alter is re `par(oma=rep(5,4))` or ..?

Comment: @CCurtis: I modified their `mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0)` to `mar = c(5, 5, 5, 5)` in their [code](https://github.com/taiyun/corrplot/blob/master/R/corrplot.R) but nothing changed. I'll further into it

Comment: @user20650: I meant the bottom margin in the attached plot so that `-1` shows up in the legend. `par(oma=rep(5,4))` didn't help

Comment: increase the size of your graphics window / graphics output device: I see all the legend labels on my screen without adjustment. So try, for example, `pdf("test.pdf", height=10, width=10) ; corrplot(...) ; dev.pff()`

Comment: @user20650: It works. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @user20650: If I save it to PNG or TIFF format, it doesn't work. Do you know why? Thanks!

Comment: have a look at `?png` and `?tiff`, they have different heoght / width units

Comment: Thanks! I have to use `png(filetag, height = 800, width = 800)` instead of `dev.copy(png, filetag, width = 800, height = 800)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28847524/r-titles-cut-in-half-with-par

Comment: I find it helps to change the *aspect ratio* of the graphics window/output device. When I'm displaying to the screen, a landscape sized window of 16:9 cuts off the top labels. But resizing the "zoom window" (R-Studio) to square, or even portrait-shaped, solves the problem. From the preceding comments the same workaround applies to PDF and PNG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer my own question for future readers

```
library(corrplot) 
library(scico)

col4 <- scico(100, palette = 'vik')
filetag <- "corrplot_result.png"

png(filetag, height = 800, width = 800)

  corrplot.mixed(cor_matrix, order = "AOE", upper = "ellipse", lower = "number", 
                 upper.col = col4, lower.col = col4,
                 tl.cex = 2, cl.cex = 2, number.cex = 2)
dev.off()
```

[image]