# Reduce whitespace in corrplot in R

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I have a 1 row 2 column plot which I need to insert into a report. When I insert the plot I notice there's a large white area around both correlation plots. Is there an argument in the corrplot function to reduce this? I've read [here](https://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/) about using knitr hook functions to crop pdfs but that a bridge too far for my coding capabilities. I've messed around with the par() arguments such as omi and mai but when I export the image to TIFF I still get a huge white space area.

My code so far looks as follows, please note this is hacked together from various sources and dputs to both correlation matrices can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19DOg4P4rclVr4cpolooocxSvnW7bSYSB/view?usp=sharing) and [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10rsSVXjBfQTWm2ffiV5aurza-k8V-WrG/view?usp=sharing):

```
col <- colorRampPalette(c("#BB4444", "#EE9988", "#FFFFFF", "#77AADD", "#4477AA"))

par(mfrow=c(1,2),omi=c(0,0,0,0),mai=c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1))

corrplot(LX0088U21A1_24hrCor, method = "color", col = col(200),
         type = "upper", order = "original", number.cex = 0.85,
         addCoef.col = "black", # Add coefficient of correlation
         tl.col = "black", tl.srt = 90,
         number.digits = 1,
         # Text label color and rotation
         # hide correlation coefficient on the principal diagonal
         diag = FALSE,
         #title = "Intraday Correlation LX0088U21A1",
         mar=c(0,0,1,0))
legend(0.5,5,ncol = 1, cex = 1.5,legend = "(a)", box.lwd = 0, box.col = "white")

corrplot(LX0088U09A3_24hrCor, method = "color", col = col(200),
         type = "upper", order = "original", number.cex = 0.75,
         addCoef.col = "black", # Add coefficient of correlation
         tl.col = "black", tl.srt = 90,
         number.digits = 1,
         # Text label color and rotation
         # hide correlation coefficient on the principal diagonal
         diag = FALSE,
         #title = "Intraday Correlation LX0088U09A3",
         mar=c(0,0,1,0))
legend(0.5,5,ncol = 1, cex = 1.5,legend = "(b)", box.lwd = 0, box.col = "white")
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: think this is more to do with the aspect ratio and your device dimensions, eg, put a `box('outer')` around your figure and increase the width of the figure in your knitr script

Comment: wow the version i have is almost 2 years old, not sure how I managed that as how my computer isnt even that old.. but the version on cran has an argument that allows you to control the aspect ratio in some figures https://github.com/cran/corrplot/blob/master/R/corrplot.R#L198:L199

Comment: Try the solution in my question https://stackoverflow.com/a/49118535/786542