# R plot (hclust) and clusplot titles cut off on top

Tags: r, plot

I am experiencing the similar problems seen in:

1. [Main title at the top of a plot is cut off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630956/main-title-at-the-top-of-a-plot-is-cut-off)
2. [R: Titles cut in half with par()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28847524/r-titles-cut-in-half-with-par)

and i tried the solutions suggested in both posts.

my code used to plot my hclust:

```
plot(hclust.train, hang = -1)
```

here's how my hclust plot look like:
[image]

as suggested in the first post mentioned above, i tried:

```
par(oma=c(0,0,2,0))
```

to add border padding; however, the plot with the border look like this:
[image]

it's simply the cut off version but moved down a bit...

here's how my clusplot plots look like (same problem):

[image]

and with the border added:
[image]

i've also tried using the argument "mar=c(0,0,2,0)", as suggested in the 2nd post mentioned in the beginning, but the result is the same as adding the border padding.

any help is appreciated.

**Edit:**
Thanks to Ben Bolker for a simple quick solution. 
After using his suggested code:

```
par(xpd=NA,oma=c(0,0,2,0))
```

i got the following improved version:
[image]

my last question would be, how to get rid of the border line that's going through the title, OR move the title position above that border line? Thank you!

Comment: hard to say without a reproducible example.  Try `par(xpd=NA,oma=c(0,0,2,0))` ?

Comment: hi @BenBolker, thank yo uso much for your suggested solution! i've edited my question to incorporate your suggestion, but i have some more question regarding clean up. would you be able to help as well? thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't give a reproducible example, but I can reproduce this *if* I set my margins to all-zero; I can work around it with `par(xpd=NA)`

```
hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave")
plot(hc)  ## looks OK
```

Setting the margins to zero cuts off the title:

```
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(hc)  ## cut off
```

Setting the outer margin doesn't help:

```
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0),oma=c(0,0,2,0)) 
plot(hc)
```

Setting `par(xpd=NA)` does help:

```
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0),xpd=NA)
plot(hc)
```

If I add `box()` I get a border line that cuts through the title.  The best thing would be to *not* set the margins to zero, or to set `par(mar=c(0,0,2,0))` to make sure there's room for the title at the top, or to use `par(oma=c(0,0,2,0))` and then use `mtext()` to add the title by hand.

Comment: Thank you so much! it solved my problem perfectly :)