# Plot title cut off with par() in R

Tags: r, plot

My plots with code:

```
set.seed(123)
x = arima.sim(n=300, model = list(ar=0.7, ma=0.5))

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
acf(x,main="Sample ACF")
pacf(x,main="Sample PACF")
```

returned output like this:
[image]
I tried to add following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631358/11901732) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28847927/11901732), with code:

```
set.seed(123)
x = arima.sim(n=300, model = list(ar=0.7, ma=0.5))

par(oma=c(0,0,2,0),mfrow=c(1,2))
acf(x,main="Sample ACF")
pacf(x,main="Sample PACF")
```

also tried:

```
set.seed(123)
x = arima.sim(n=300, model = list(ar=0.7, ma=0.5))

par(par(xpd=NA),mfrow=c(1,2))
acf(x,main="Sample ACF")
pacf(x,main="Sample PACF")
```

but results didn't change.

Comment: The figure looks good with the code in the first block. Have you tried to run it in a clean R session?

Comment: Hi @mt1022 I was using R markdown. I tried to run it in a new R script and it seemed okay. Is there a way to do it in markdown?

Comment: I included the code in a markdown file and the figure in the resulting html file also looks fine. I guess you modified parameters of  `par` somewhere else and forgot to restore it. Could you try `par(mfrow=c(1,2), mar = c(5, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1)`?

Comment: @mt1022 trying your code worked, thank you! But my plot remained the same. I don't quite understand how I modified the parameters, could you please tell me how I could restore the parameters? Please feel free to post your answer below

Comment: Any call to `par` (including `par=` as mentioned) is held constant for a particular graphics until that device is closed or something else changes it. For instance, run `par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))` and then plot anything. Then plot something completely different, no change. Now close the device (either its window or call `dev.off()`) and try a plot again without calling `par`.

Comment: Except for calling `dev.off()` as mentioned by r2evans, you can also save the parameters before modification. Try this example `x <- par(mar = rep(0, 4)); plot(1:10); par(x); plot(1:10)`. `x` is a list that holds the parameters before the modification takes effects and calling `par(x)` restores those parameter values.

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for the explanation. This worked for me, though calling `dev.off()` at the beginning of the plot caught error `Error in dev.off() : cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)`. However with `dev.off`by removing the brackets it didn't seem to be a problem. Am I using it correctly?

Comment: It's a function, so just calling `dev.off` *does* very little. If it's just `mar` then you can reinstate the defaults with `par(mar=c(5,4,4,2)+0.1)`, without the need to close the device. My biggest concern (and why I didn't suggest that in the first place) is that it seems likely more than one parameter might have been changed, so I didn't want to reset just one.

Comment: @r2evans So with consideration to the aforementioned error message, where should we add the `dev.off()`?

Comment: @r2evans Thanks I think it's working now